# Android AlertDialog setOnDismissListener for API lower than 17

Tags: java, android, dialog

I created an AlertDialog:

```
private CharSequence[] _items = { "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4",
"item5", "item6", "item7" };

AlertDialog.Builder daysBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    daysBuilder.setTitle("SomeCaption");

    daysBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(_items,new Boolean[] { false, true, false, 
false false false, true }, SetListener);
    daysBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", OKListener);
    daysBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", CancelListener);

    AlertDialog alert = daysBuilder.create();
    alert.show();`
```

Through the statement "`new Boolean[] { false, true, false false false false, true }`" the items
in the dialog get checked/unchecked by default.

When I open the dialog, change the selection of the items but then dismiss (by pressing cancel or the back-button of the device) the dialog gets dismissed. So far so good.

But when I reopen the dialog, the items have the checked/unchecked state of the previous changes from the last opening of the dialog.

But when the dialog was dismissed at the first opening, I want to have the items checked/unchecked state like when I created the dialog (`new Boolean[] { false, true, false false false false, true }`).

So basically I need an opportunity to get notified when the dialog gets dissmissed so I can then reset the state of the items.

I tried it with the setOnDismissListener for the dialog object. Unfortunately this is just available in API 17.

setOnDismissListener worked perfect for me (exactly what I need) in the emulator (API 17) but not on my device (Android 4.1 => API 16)

Is there something similar in API 16?

Comment: [setOnDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29)  is present from Api level 1

Comment: hmm thank you for your answer. But even Eclipse is complaining that SetOnDismissListener is only for API17 and gives me an warning at     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16" <=== warning
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

I can suppress the warning but then the app crashes on my Device...Eclipse also tells me that setOnDismissListener was added in API17

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The problem is you are using `setOnDismissListener` of `AlertDialog.Builder`. This was introduced in Api level 17, `setOnDismissListener` of `AlertDialog` itself has been since api level 1.

```
AlertDialog alert = daysBuilder.create();
alert.setOndismissListener(yourdismisslistener);
alert.show();`
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520597/android-illegalstateexception-you-can-not-set-dialogs-oncancellistener-or-on