# IllegalStateException( "You can not set Dialog's OnCancelListener or OnDismissListener")

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

This DialogFragment implementation causes an

> IllegalStateException( "You can not set Dialog's OnCancelListener or
>   OnDismissListener")

. Why? Solution?

```
public class OkCThreadDialog1 extends DialogFragment{

DialogInterface.OnCancelListener onCancelListener;

public OkCThreadDialog1(){
}

public static OkCThreadDialog1 newInstance(String title, String message) {
    OkCThreadDialog1 frag = new OkCThreadDialog1();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    args.putString("message", message);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}


public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());


    builder .setTitle(getArguments().getString("title"))
            .setMessage(getArguments().getString("message"))
            .setOnCancelListener(onCancelListener)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }})
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    getDialog().cancel();
                }});

    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try {
        onCancelListener = (DialogInterface.OnCancelListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OkCancelDialogListener");
    }
}
}
```

My Activity implements `DialogInterface.OnCancelListener` as follow:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OkCancelDialogListener{

static final String TAG ="MainActivity";

@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {


}
}
```

Exeception is thrown from `builder.create();`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

From [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle)):

> public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState)
>
> Override to build your own custom Dialog container. This is
> typically used to show an AlertDialog instead of a generic Dialog;
> when doing so, onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) does
> not need to be implemented since the AlertDialog takes care of its own
> content.
>
> This method will be called after onCreate(Bundle) and before
> onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle). The default
> implementation simply instantiates and returns a Dialog class.
>
> **Note: DialogFragment own the Dialog.setOnCancelListener and Dialog.setOnDismissListener callbacks. You must not set them yourself.**
>
> **To find out about these events, override onCancel(DialogInterface) and
> onDismiss(DialogInterface).**

So basically, you must override the onDismiss or OnCancel instead of '.setOnCancelListener(onCancelListener)'.

Answer (score 6):

You may try this:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setMessage("Message");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // do something positive
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    // do something
}
```

Hope it can help ...

Answer (score 0):

You set the OnCancelListener for a dialog not for its builder.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder .setTitle(getArguments().getString("title"))
        .setMessage(getArguments().getString("message"))
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }})
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                getDialog().cancel();
            }});

    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setOnCancelListener(onCancelListener);
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me either. I just used the solution in accepted answer.

Answer (score -3):

Try this code i hope this will be work..

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            class_name.this);
    builder.setTitle("Title");      
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {            

    });


    dialog.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
    dialog.show();
```