# DialogFragment OnDismissListener not working

Tags: java, android

i created a DialogFragment with a layout which contains a listview with some items and wanna do something with the value of the selected item but when i try to set the OnDismissListener it gives me an error.
If someone could help me, here is the code snippet where the error occurs.
When the execution reaches the *dialog.getDialog().setOnDismissListener*... then it gives the exception

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

PopupRecentBanderolNrs dialog = new PopupRecentBanderolNrs();

dialog.listitems[0] = GetFileContentsFromInternalStorage();
dialog.show(manager, "dialog");

manager.executePendingTransactions();
dialog.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
          ... some code ..,
    }
});
```

Comment: show your logcat error pls

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: OnDismissListener is already taken by DialogFragment and can not be replaced.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520597/illegalstateexception-you-can-not-set-dialogs-oncancellistener-or-ondismissli

Answer (score 0):

`DialogFragment` already implements `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener`, You can override the `onDismiss()` method in your `PopupRecentBanderolNrs` class.

if you want set your Listener, you can set in `onCreateDialog` method:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = ...;// your dialog
    dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

        }
    });
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: I want to override the ondismisslistener in another activity so that i can make use of the value selected in the dialog

Comment: Using the second way, get the Dialog in `onCreateDialog` method, and set the `OnDismissListener`.  When dialog is showing , you can not call the `setOnDismissListener`,so you code 
 `dialog.getDialog().setOnDismissListener` will cause the Exception.

Comment: I still cant figure it out , how to do it, because i want to get the value of the selecteditem in the listview which is in the dialogfragment and use it in my calling activity as i cant override onCreateDialog on my calling activity

Comment: override `onCreateDialog` in your `PopupRecentBanderolNrs` class.