# Updating UI after dialog dismissed

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have activity A which have a ListView with custom adapter.

The custom adapter (which aplies to each list view item) have a button which invokes a custom dialog.

in this dialog an action is being performed which in response i want to invoke UI update on activity A.

This is my activity on resume code:

```
@Override
public void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    setUI();  
}
```

But when the i call

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

The dialog closes without the Activity A OnResume method benig invoked.

How can i catch and update the activity ui?

Comment: You can use [onDismmiss()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830899/android-wait-for-user-input-at-alertdialog-to-proceed/18831531#18831531)

Comment: But my dialog is inside the adapter class not the activity class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually its very easy - you can cast the Context inside the adapter to the calling containing activity:

```
ActivityName activity = (ActivityName )con;
activity.setUI();
```

Comment: Its better to use a callback/listener

Answer (score 7):

You can set an `OnDismissListener` to your dialog to achieve this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setOnDismissListener(listener);
...
Dialog dialog = builder.create();
```

You can let your Activity impelement `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener` and set them as the listener, so they get notified in the method `onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)`. In there, you can update your UI.

Comment: But my dialog is inside the adapter class not the activity class

Comment: Well, it does not have to be your activity, you can also let your adapter implement the OnDismissListener and add it as a listener.

Comment: keep in mind this requires a min API level 17.. check this other solution for lower than 17 API levels.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933077/android-setondismisslistern-for-api-lower-than-17